# mysql reset root user privileges

Tags: mysql, root, privileges, sql-grant

I have installed wampserver. i revoke the the delete privilege from root user. now i want to grant same privilege back to root user but it gives the error:

i tried the following command

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

but the command gives the

```
#1045 - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

there are two root users

```
root localhost
root 127.0.0.1
```

root localhost do not have DELETE privilege. root 127.0.0.1 have all privileges. i   tried with `http://127.0.0.1/phpmyadmin` but the same error occurs. is there a way to reset root user privileges.

Answer (score 0):

I have had issues with `GRANT ... TO 'user'@'%' ...` before. Try to additionally issue the following GRANT statement:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

For me, this did the trick. Somehow mysql seems picky when it comes to localhost

Comment: same error ... #1045 - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Comment: Sorry to hear that. I have no more ideas currently about this. Did you only try via php-admin or also directly on the mysql console?